# How to retrieve a field from a source table based on two values in a pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a Microsoft Excel table like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2023-01-31 |
| 4 | B | 2023-04-02 |
| 2 | C | 2023-05-02 |
| 1 | D | 2023-06-02 |
| 2 | E | 2023-01-30 |
| 3 | F | 2023-03-02 |

I created a **pivot table** that retrieves the count of values in column B and the minimum value in column C that match each value in column A:

| A | Count of B | Min of C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-01-31 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-01-30 |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-03-02 |
| 4 | 1 | 2023-04-02 |
| Grand Total | 6 | 2023-01-30 |

How could I add a column retrieving a value in column B (does not matter which) that matches A and Min of C. Something like:

| A | Count of B | Min of C | col. B pick |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-01-31 | A |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-01-30 | E |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-03-02 | F |
| 4 | 1 | 2023-04-02 | B |
| Grand Total | 6 | 2023-01-30 |  |

Thank you!

I feel I need to use one of the lookup functions, but not sure how to add a function to the pivot table or even how to apply it to the source table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any one of the following --> approaches shown using <kbd>NEW MS365 EXCEL FORMULAS</kbd> & <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, UNIQUE(A2:A7),
     b, COUNTIFS(A2:A7,a),
     c, MINIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,a),
     d, MAP(a&"|"&c,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,A2:A7&"|"&C2:C7,B2:B7,""))),
     e, SORT(HSTACK(a,b,c,d)),
     VSTACK({"A","Count of B","Min of C","Col. B Pick"},e,
     HSTACK("Grand Total ",SUM(INDEX(e,,2)),MIN(DROP(e,,2)),"")))
```

---

May be there is a more elegant way of doing this using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>, but yes you can easily accomplish this task.

[image]

---

To perform the task using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>, follow the steps:

---

- First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the **Power Query** window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"A", Int64.Type}, {"B", type text}, {"C", type date}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"A"}, {{"Count of B", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}, {"Min of C", each List.Min([C]), type nullable date}, {"Col B. Pick", each _, type table [A=nullable number, B=nullable text, C=nullable date]}}),
    #"Expanded Col B. Pick" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Col B. Pick", {"B", "C"}, {"B", "C"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Col B. Pick",{{"A", Order.Ascending}, {"C", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows", {"A"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Removed Duplicates",{"C"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Excel file for download : **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckAgBkWzsaV2D9E3E?e=YNrYlB)**

---